# How does using my credit card through the Wallet app appear to the merchant?

Tags: iphone, apple-pay, wallet

I thought adding a card to the wallet app would mean you can just tap with your phone instead of the physical card and it appears identical to the merchant as using the original card.

Through further research I learned using Wallet in reality uses Apple Pay which provides a unique Apple Pay number, and possibly other personal information inputted into Wallet.

This thread on Apple Forums states Postal Code, Shipping Address might be shared. (see [Does Apple Pay share cardholder name or billing address with apps, websites, or merchants?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253453334)) But I can't find this information on Apple's own page about [Apple Pay security and privacy overview](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT203027). Instead, they vaguely state:

> along with additional information needed to complete the transaction

Apple Pay's marketing repeatedly states how it protects your privacy, but it seems it's capable of sharing more information than a simple card tap would (Card number, Cardholder name, and expiry).

I'm wondering what else Apply Pay could share potentially share as "additional information". Could phone Number, and Apple ID Email also be shared?

Under what circumstances is information shared?

Comment: It's possible additional information is shared when requested by online stores and apps like stated in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374845/362893

Comment: In Settings -> Wallet & Apple Pay, there is a Transaction Defaults section with Shipping Address, Email, and Phone. Those can all be removed. And each added card has a Billing Address field in Card Details inside Wallet.

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to agree with the body… and why do you keep adding information in comments underneath? Please edit into one coherent question.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the linked page on Security and Privacy, Apple Pay doesn't  use your credit card number when you use it, but instead uses a token that is created by your bank and assures the bank that this is an authentic transaction from an authentic banking customer. It's not a temporary credit card number or a virtual one: its a Device Primary Account Number that your bank can use to map to your account (each device has a different DPAN). Apple actually provides the last 4 digits of your real credit card number for cases where this is needed for verification or if the credit card holder wants to see what card was charged.

When you use Apple Pay at a credit card accepting terminal, its sends only this information (and other non-identifying banking info). No billing address, etc.

However, when you use Apple Pay on a website or an app, it can  send address and other information, that you have provided in the Apple Pay System Settings panel. It is not taking this from the Bank.

This is only done with requested by the Merchant. If you order pizza delivery, it needs your address for delivery of the pizza. Or if you order online it needs your address for tax calculation.

This is from the fine print on Apple Pay:

> Information Shared When You Make a Payment
>
> When you begin a payment within an app, on the web, or within Apple Messages for Business using Apple Pay, to enable tax and shipping cost calculation your zip code, postal code, or other equivalent information is provided to the app, website, or merchant. After you authorize the payment, other information requested by the merchant, such as a device- or merchant-specific account number, your shipping address, or email address, is also provided. The card number from your credit, debit, or prepaid card is not provided when you use Apple Pay.

Comment: The card number used by Apple Pay is different from the actual card number, but it's not temporary. It's unique to the device, but assigned permanently.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I was simplifying too much, added additional details, as it is not a credit card number at all

Comment: Thanks cmason, so when paying at a terminal it will only send the minimum required to complete the transaction which doesn't include the card holder name so it is in essence more private than paying by physical card, correct? Where as when paying in app or online, the app or website could pull any of the information added under Billing Address in the card, or Shipping Address, email address or phone number in Wallet settings?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Debit / Credit Card to your Wallet in your iPhone, it gets registered in Apple Pay. Any purchases you make using your Wallet app are made through Apple Pay.

Apple Pay has the potential of sending different amounts of personal information depending on whether you use it in store, in an app, or on a website.

### In Store

When you use your Wallet app to pay in store, the merchant receives the following information:

1. The last 4 digits of your card (Source: [In Apple Pay, why does the merchant see my real credit card number?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7938028))
2. The last 4 digits of your Apple Pay Number (Device account number)

### In App or Online

When you use your Wallet app to pay in an app or online, the merchant receives the following information:

1. The last 4 digits of your card, including the Card Name and Card Type
2. The last 4 digits of your Apple Pay Number (Device account number)
3. It can optionally share as requested by the merchant your Card's Billing Address in the card details in Wallet.
4. It can optionally share as requested by the merchant your Shipping Address, Phone Number, and Email as set in `Settings -> Wallet & Apple Pay -> Transaction Defaults` or provided on the spot while in the checkout page.

Source: [Apple Pay on the Web requires my phone and email. Is that information shared?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374845/362893)

Comment: It's unclear to me if Billing Address attached to the card in Wallet card details is automatically shared with merchants even when paying in store, but I would think not as it's possible to remove Billing Address altogether from the card in question.

Comment: Again, you are adding additional information in comments. Please make your question/answer stands on its own & not rely on additional comments, which are ephemeral & may be swept up at any time.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere notwithstanding another question: as mentioned in my answer, when paying at a credit card accepting terminal, address is not transfered as it is not part of the transaction with the merchant. But online, it is, again depending on the merchant.